# Abstract method returns base class. What does it mean?

Tags: scala, abstract-class

What does the following mean and how i can use it?

```
abstract class An_Abstract_Class {
   def A_method(x : Int) : An_Abstract_Class
}
```

I know that there cannot be an instance or object from an abstract class, so what this method actually returns?

Can this be used for the creation of a list or a binary tree?

Is this is better techique than a concrete class and why?

Comment: Abstract class is a model for other class, you need to implement it - they don't hold an implementation for methods. You are expected to create class, that inherited from an abstract and override methods.

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, this class is abstract so there can't be any direct instances of it. That means that there will need to be subclasses and those subclasses must implement `A_method`. What will those subclasses return? Instances of themselves, perhaps, and since they are subclasses of `An_Abstract_Class` they satisfy the return type.

For example:

```
class A_Concrete_Class extends An_Abstract_Class {
  def A_method(x:Int) : An_Abstract_Class = this
}
```

Interestingly, you could also do this:

```
class A_Concrete_Class extends An_Abstract_Class {
  def A_method(x:Int) : A_Concrete_Class = this
}
```

The difference is that the overridden `A_method` has specified a return type of `A_Concrete_Class`. Since this is a sub-class of `An_Abstract_Class` the compile is fine with it. This is known as a "co-variant return type" - i.e. the return type of a sub-class implementation is allowed to be a sub-type of the base-class return type.

You can indeed use this kind of thing to implement a binary tree, though in Scala a more idiomatic approach to that would be to use a trait and case class implementations.